# Remove cache URL with SDWebImage and FirebaseStorageUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I'm using `FirebaseStorageUI` to download images using Firebase in my iOS project. Everything worked perfect, up to a point where there's no documentation about the issue I have.

I usually clear SDWebImage's cache of one specific url using this:

```
SDImageCache.shared().removeImage(forKey: "value", fromDisk: true, withCompletion: nil)
```

However, with Firebase there are only `FIRStorageReference` objects used to retrieve the images, therefore the only method I see to successfully accomplish what I want is to do this:

```
ref.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    // code  
}
```

This is quite tedious work, given the fact that I already have a plethora of closures to handle only the interactions with Firebase. Is this the single way to clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) instead. It comes with an extension to `UIImageView` that simplifies downloading images from urls.

```
let url = URL(string: "image_url")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

To manually clear the image cache used by Kingfisher:

```
ImageCache.default.clearDiskCache()
```